# Package Manager installation for Linux from scratch (LFS)

Tags: linux, boot, debian, package-management

I have successfully build Linux based system using Linux from scratch.
Now I want to install Debian (dpkg/apt) package manager for updating my packages.

I have used below mentioned hint as a reference 
Installing and using pacman as a package manager for LFS

http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/hints/2013-March/003304.html

To achieve my goal i have followed below path.

1. I have followed LFS book (created a chroot environment, essential directories and Symlinks) and instead of installing packages from source I have installed dpkg and its dependencies from source.
2. After that i have installed all packages (including their dependencies) by using their .deb package from debian.org (Package are as per LFS book 8.0)
3. After completing installation of packages required for minimum bootable system and network related packages, I installed Linux kernel and grub with hope that this system will boot

When i try to boot this system. It was unable to boot and throwing error as shown in attachment [boot_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7Cp.png). The apparent error is as follow

```
starting init: /etc/init exists but could't execute (error -13)
```

So my queries are,

1. Am i following the correct path for installing debian based package manager?
2. If you have some suggestions regarding this then do share your views
3. What could be the reason for this error?

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with LFS, but it seems to me like `/etc/init` should not be executed as it is normally a directory with init files. It should execute `/(s)bin/init`. Hope this helps.